# Get the Last insert Id in Symfony2 doctrine2 query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Get the Last insert Id in Symfony2 doctrine2 query

```
    $apptQuery = "insert into tbl_student_scores (test_date,updated_by_id) values(:testDate,:loggedinUser)";
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $Querystatement = $connection->prepare($apptQuery);
    $Querystatement->bindValue('testDate', $test->test_date);
    $Querystatement->bindValue('loggedinUser', $loggedinUser);
    if($Querystatement->execute()){
           var_dump($connection->lastInsertId()); // control coming here but the outpur is bool(false)
    }else{
            echo "query not executed"; 
    }
```

but the output coming as empty when i wrote below query.

```
var_dump($connection->lastInsertId());
```

Comment: change :-`$Querystatement->execute();` to `if($Querystatement->execute()){$connection->lastInsertId();}else{ echo "query not executed";}` and check

Comment: yes i updated the code but output coming as 'bool(false)' inside if

Comment: sorry do `var_dump($connection->lastInsertId());` inside `if` condition

Comment: Yes, i did the same as you can see that in my updated question. its returning  `bool(false)`

Comment: Inside `if` do this:- `$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$conn->lastInsertId(' put id column name here');`. remove `var_dump()` code and add this code and check. Don't forget to provide id column name there

Answer (score 1):

Try the Below Code.

```
$apptQuery = "insert into tbl_student_scores (test_date,updated_by_id) values(:testDate,:loggedinUser)";
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$Querystatement = $connection->prepare($apptQuery);
$Querystatement->bindValue('testDate', $test->test_date);
$Querystatement->bindValue('loggedinUser', $loggedinUser);
$Querystatement->execute();
$insertID = $Querystatement->fetchAll();
$scoreId = $insertID[0]['id'];
```